# How do I inject deep linking query parameters into appLinkData when using Facebook app links on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My question is predicated on Jason Clark’s statement at f8 2014 that app links is designed to sit side by side well with deep linking technologies. I have a word game app published in 2013 to Canada and Australia using Facebook’s authentication but without deep linking.  For the US market launch my intent was to add Facebook deep linking. Managed with the request and feed dialogs to send the Match Identifier UUID for both initiating a match and then bragging about the match (FriendSmash example) at that time to open the game on that match. My day job got in the way and I did not have time to finish QA and support a launch to the US. Last summer I upgraded SDKs (Facebook 3.14) and the url query no longer contained the string ‘notif’ to allow me to parse for the match Id. Therefore, I switched from using [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url] to the current [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url …] and some other code from the new FriendSmash example. However, the url passed from the Facebook app no longer contains the ‘ref’ and therefore not the ‘notif’ which was the method documented to utilize my deep linking content. I have since updated my project to Facebook iOS SDK 3.21 (predicated in part by other SDKs, e.g. AWS not supporting arm64).

I currently use the following code to send the brag

```
- (void) sendBrag
{
    // This function will invoke the Feed Dialog to post to a user's Timeline and News Feed
    // It will attemnt to use the Facebook Native Share dialog
    // If that's not supported we'll fall back to the web based dialog.


    NSArray *friend = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: bragMatch.opponentFacebookId, nil];
    NSString *linkURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ruleofwords.com/?deeplink_matchno=%@", bragMatch.initiatorMatchNo];

    //NSString *linkURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ruleofwords.com"];
    NSString *pictureURL = @"https://pacific-castle-1361.herokuapp.com/rowappicon.png";
    NSMutableString *msg = [[NSMutableString alloc]
                            initWithString:@"Just scored 0 points in Rule of Words. Good luck trying to beat that."];

    [msg replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:bragMatch.initiatorMatchPoints
                            options:NSBackwardsSearch range: NSMakeRange(0, [msg length])];


    // Prepare the native share dialog parameters
    FBLinkShareParams *shareParams = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
    shareParams.friends = friend;
    shareParams.link = [NSURL URLWithString:linkURL];
    shareParams.name = @"Rule of Words Bragging Rights";
    shareParams.caption= msg;
    shareParams.picture= [NSURL URLWithString:pictureURL];
    shareParams.linkDescription = @"Rule of Words, the contagious photography word social game on iPhone.";

    if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:shareParams]){

        [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:shareParams
                                    clientState:nil
                                        handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                            if(error) {
                                                NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
                                            } else if (results[@"completionGesture"] && [results[@"completionGesture"] isEqualToString:@"cancel"]) {
                                                NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                                            } else {
                                                NSLog(@"Story published.");
                                            }
                                        }];

    } else {

        // Prepare the web dialog parameters
        NSDictionary *params = @{
                                 @"to": bragMatch.opponentFacebookId,
                                 @"name" : shareParams.name,
                                 @"caption" : shareParams.caption,
                                 @"description" : shareParams.linkDescription,
                                 @"picture" : pictureURL,
                                 @"link" : linkURL
                                 };

        // Invoke the dialog
        [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                               parameters:params
                                                  handler:
         ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"Error publishing story %@.", error);
             } else {
                 if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                     NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                 } else {
                     NSLog(@"Story published.");
                 }
             }}];
    }
}
```

(Aside - In my stepping through the sendBrag code the FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams always fails so that every time it defaults to a feed dialog. Anyone know what is the state is where the share dialog works? )

Then in my AppDelegate I have…

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    NSLog(@"app is %@ and url is %@ and sourceApp is %@", application, url, sourceApplication);
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                    fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                        // If there is an active session
                        if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
                            // Check the incoming link
                            [self handleAppLinkData:call.appLinkData];
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"Access Token is %@", call.accessTokenData);
                            if (call.accessTokenData) {
                              // If token data is passed in and there's
                              // no active session.
                              if ([self handleAppLinkToken:call.accessTokenData]) {
                                // Attempt to open the session using the
                                // cached token and if successful then
                                // check the incoming link
                                [self handleAppLinkData:call.appLinkData];
                              }
                            }
                        }
                    }];

- (void) handleAppLinkData:(FBAppLinkData *)appLinkData {

    NSURL *targetURL = appLinkData.targetURL;
    if (targetURL) {
        //NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:targetURLString];
        NSDictionary *targetParams = [self parseURLParams:[targetURL query]];
        NSString *ref = [targetParams valueForKey:@"ref"];
        // Check if ref parm is among incoming news feed link, otw attribution link
        if ([ref isEqualToString:@"notif"]) {
            // Get the request id
            NSString *requestIDParam = targetParams[@"request_ids"];
            NSArray *requestIDs = [requestIDParam
                                   componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

            // Get data (of last request) from Graph API call to request id endpoint
            // 
            [self notificationGet:requestIDs[[requestIDs count]-1]];
        }
    }
} 

- (void) notificationGet:(NSString *)requestid {
    __block NSString *title;
    __block NSString *message;

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:requestid
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
                if (! error) {
                if (result[@"data"]) 
                 {
                      title = [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%@ requests a match!", result[@"from"][@"name"]];
                          NSString *jsonString = result[@"data"];
              NSData *jsonData = [jsonString                                        dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                          if (!jsonData) {
                          NSLog(@"JSON decode error: %@", error);
                          return;
                          }
                          NSError *jsonError = nil;
                          NSDictionary *requestData =[NSJSONSerialization                               JSONObjectWithData:jsonData                                                                                                         options:0
                                                                                                                      error:&jsonError];
                        if (jsonError) {
                          NSLog(@"JSON decode error: %@", error);
                          return;
                        }
                        message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Match #: %@, Flashes: %@",
                                       requestData[@"deeplink_matchno"],
                                       requestData[@"flashes_gifted"]];
                       // set global opponentFacebookId for bragging
                      [[rowGlobals sharedGlobalVars]                                        setRowGlobal:requestData[@"deeplink_matchno"]
                                    forKey:@"deeplink_matchno"] ;

                        // Set up FB Deep Link Notification
                // homeViewController is registered for notification
                      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                         postNotificationName:FBDeepLinkNotification
                                       object:requestData[@"deeplink_matchno"]];
                       NSLog(@"successfully posted DeepLink notification") ;

                    } else {
                      title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ sent you a request",                      result[@"from"][@"name"]];
                        message = result[@"message"];
                    }

                                  // Delete the request notification
                    [self notificationClear:result[@"id"]];
            } else {
                title = @"General Deep Link Error" ;
                message = @"Error occured with Facebook FBRequest Connection. This Facebook notification likely has been previously processed." ;
            }
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil,
                                                    nil];
            [alert show];

        }];
}
```

Now I recognize I have some clean up to align the dialog setup with how I parse appLinkData to get the matchId UUID for my NSNotification to open on the game, but I am not getting that far to bother cleaning it up.

I have tried many meta tags on my site but at the moment I am just using

```
<meta property=”al:ios:url” content=”ruleofwords”>
```

where ruleofwords is a custom URL I added to my app’s plist.

but I cannot seem to put together any URL other than

```
NSString *linkURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ruleofwords.com"];
```

which will launch my game by clicking on the Facebook link…

When I use anything like

```
NSString *urlLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.ruleofwords.com/?deeplink_matchNo=%@", bragMatch.initiatorMatchNo];
```

Then Facebook will only launch my web page without the custom URL link to my game.

Moreover, Facebook no longer launches it directly; it brings up my web page with an added link displayed as the offset brackets app Links logo.(Although not explicit it does technically follow the Facebook flow [diagram](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios)). Touching this app Link logo does launch my game. This seems to be the case whether I have the meta tag on my website or not (now I may have other problems since we are only using Godaddy website builder).

Previously with the request dialog I had the ability to populate values such as @”data” with things like my match Id and gifts

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
           dataWithJSONObject:@{
                                @"deeplink_matchno": bragMatch.initiatorMatchNo,
                                @"flashes_gifted": @"0"}
                        options:0
                        error:&error];
    if (!jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"JSON error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSString *challengeStr = [[NSString alloc]
                              initWithData:jsonData
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableDictionary *params = 
  [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                                                            
     bragMatch.opponentFacebookId, @"to",
     @"Rule of Words Bragging", @"name",
     msg, @"caption",
     @"Rule of Words, the contagious photography word social game on iPhone.",
       @"description",
    urlLink, @"link",
    @"https://pacific-castle-6969.herokuapp.com/rowappicon.png", @"picture",
   challengeStr, @"data",
   nil];

    // Invoke the dialog
    //[self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
    //[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                  message:msg
                                                    title:nil
                                               parameters:params
                                                  handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             // Case A: Error launching the dialog or publishing story.
             NSString *errormsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error encountered posting Facebook brag with error %@", error.localizedDescription];
             NSLog(@"%@", errormsg);
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Facebook Brag Error"
                                   message:errormsg
                                   delegate:nil
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                   otherButtonTitles: nil];
             [alert show];
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                 // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                 NSLog(@"Player canceled Facebook brag post via x icon.");
             } else {
                 // Case C: Dialog shown and the user clicks Cancel or Share
                 NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                 //if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                if ([urlParams valueForKey:@"error_code"]) {
                // User clicked the Cancel button
                     NSLog(@"error message is %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"error_message"]);
                     NSLog(@"Player canceled Facebook brag post via Cancel button.");
                 } else {
                     // User clicked the Share button
                     //NSString *postID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"];
                     NSString *postID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                     NSLog(@"Player Successfuly Posted RoW Match via Facebook brag, id: %@", postID);
                 }
             }
         }
     }];
```

However, I no longer have al_applink_data in the passed URL for this request dialog, it just has an access_token with the original custom URL.

url is fb407545862655947://authorize/#access_token=CAAFyqSpfj8sBAGxahmdTCl1D9fs5hZBt3OfKP2MHCtM8STHadqEjlyFnXDTNHScjsxZCI6q0H8ZAppNSqJIJt83uN4LemkfklLjOdPTv3JZBtg3xTVZBKOhzdOMaZCGob5x2FPddZBzmaZBhIaE8dIgNqPfi9IlEuwQ2oHq6tEgA1w1pNESnHuDyK9gD7vswAC93nO7cCmCT4KBgxI22UDB3nINYZA058g8AZD&expires_in=3600 and sourceApp is com.facebook.Facebook

When I add the @”data” param with

```
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:…]
```

although this argument is accepted by the feed dialog I the url does not get my match UUID or anything extra from my @”data” param…

url is ruleofwords:///?al_applink_data=%7B%22target_url%22%3A%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.ruleofwords.com%5C%2F%22%2C%22extras%22%3A%7B%22fb_ref%22%3A%22Default%22%7D%2C%22referer_app_link%22%3A%7B%22url%22%3A%22fb%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%5C%2F%3Fbacktrack_id%3Ddlr5p6iu_6a-OeUn%22%2C%22app_name%22%3A%22Facebook%22%7D%7D and sourceApp is com.facebook.Facebook

So I am at a loss how I am supposed to inject content specific information so that I can open my game with the match, which the opponent has requested or bragged about. I probably would have given up a long time ago but I did once have deep linking working (SDK 3.5?).  I am wondering if I should be at another release level of the SDK for deep linking. It seems like the Facebook platform has significantly changed how it packages appLinkData. And although Facebook’s documentation has improved over the past two years, many of the examples which are required to put this all together do not seem to be referring to the same level of SDK.  So Facebook how do I inject content into appLinkData so I can support deep linking with SDK 3.21? I thought about adding the Bolts framework but Jason implied it was designed for outlinking apps, which is not my case.

I can directly type in my iPhone Safari something like ‘ruleofwords://matchId=UUID’ and get the app delegate to parse out the [url query] so I could probably implement deep linking with push notifications, but I still like the ability to have a Facebook user tap on a link and launch the specific match directly.

Comment: www.ruleofwords.com doesn't seem to be up, so I can't confirm, but I have a couple of questions, and a couple of suggestions for you. 1. Do you have deep linking turned ON for your app in your FB app settings? 2. Have you always just seen the fb407545862655947://authorize... url come in to your AppDelegate? 3. Your al:ios:url meta property is wrong, the content should be "ruleofwords://", otherwise it's not a valid url (you should validate the web url here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). 4. @"data" is not a valid parameter for the share dialog, adding that will not do anything.

Comment: 1. Deep linking has been turned on since spring of 2013

Comment: @MingLi 1. Yes since spring 2013. 2. No, in July 2013 was returning appLinkData with target_url, ref and notif information (I think using iOS SDK 3.5). 3. As defined, OG Object Debugger was still inferring http://www.ruleofwords.com from raw tags and clicking launched site so not sure why you had issues but changed to your recommendation. 4. Is there a dialog which still takes @"data" so I can inject that info and be able to parse out my RoW content (e.g. FBAppCall.appLinkData) or some other param or can you recommend an SDK where I can get feed dialog working again? Thanks - Kurt

Comment: The website issue could have been temporary, I could not reach it earlier. However, even if I put http://www.ruleofwords.com/ into the debugger now, it's giving me errors, which is probably why it's not giving you the right app links data (FB relies on our scraper to give the right metadata, and right now it's not seeing anything for your url). Lastly, there's no dialog that takes @"data", and it would be wrong for you to try to inject it because it would go against the point of app links in the first place.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you're now getting the fb407545862655947://authorize url because the FB scraper cannot scrape your website with appropriate tags, and is now falling back to the old "deep linking" behavior (which gives you the fb407545862655947://authorize url instead of the app links url).

Comment: BTW, I also see <meta property="al" content="ruleofwords://" /> from the debugger, but it should be <meta property="al:ios:url" content="ruleofwords://" />

Comment: I have been thinking about how the SDK no longer uses @"data" in the params anymore and that such injection goes against the point of app links. (Note that feed dialog still accepts @"data" but evidently recently deprecated it use, as can be shown by putting it into params, whereas a random dictionary element say @"ref" results in "This dialog has been presented a bad parameter"). Since both app links and deep linking both use the appLinKData.targetURL does that not preclude having them side by side in a single app?

Comment: I have determined that I need a new hosting service though, since godaddy website builder somehow makes a circular reference with the fetched and canonical URL, so i will look into that. I probably should use the no web site version, but wanted to get this working before I took that on as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by @"data". AFAIK, none of the dialogs have ever supported a data field. As for app links vs deep links, yes, you should choose one and stick with it. I would recommend app links as it's more powerful and less error prone.

Comment: I would be glad to go with app links, but I have not found a way to provide context specific data through that facility. When a player wants to brag about his score on a particular match, I want to pass the match UUID through app links so that the app can be launched with that match open. I understood only deep linking could do that, but would be happy to learn how to do that with app links. @MingLi - Kurt

Comment: For app links, you share an URL. Just put the UUID as a parameter on the url, something like: http://foo.com/match?uuid={id}, and then get the target_url from the incoming app link using the SDK (or bolts), and get the uuid from that.